# Does using PK and FK effect performance in negative way?

Tags: sql-server, performance, foreign-key, clustered-index, clustered-primary-key

Few companies I noticed do not use PKs and FKs. I don't understand the logic of not using Clustered Indexes and I hear some say it can cause issues because FK couples records together and takes up more memory. Any insight?

Comment: as it is a constraint, it will take time to chekc this constraint and it must be sored so it take some small  space

Comment: Both negative **and** positive! They can slow INSERTs and UPDATEs but can speed up SELECTs and/or JOINs! It's up to the database professional (DBA/programmer) to construct their indexes and foreign keys appropriately - I would strongly recommend that in the **vast** majority of cases, an FK is appropriate when values from one table are used in another and there is a parent-child relationship between them. PKs enforce uniqueness - a very important concept in DBs - if your field(s) has/have to be unique, then you can use a PK - or a surrogate key with a UNIQUE constraint on the "real" fields...

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @Vérace,@nbk for your answer.

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168602/36809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tag which database system and version you're referring to, as this could affect the answer that is appropriate. But assuming you mean one of the main modern relational database systems, there's a couple of different objects you're asking about, so here's an answer for each of them:

**Primary Keys**:

They do not affect performance in a negative way at all, and in fact can slightly help performance in certain database systems because they guarantee uniqueness on a set of fields in the table. It is bad relational design in *most* cases to not define a **primary key** on a table. **Primary keys** are **not** the same thing as **clustered indexes**, though some database systems will create the **clustered index** on the **primary key** fields by default, out of assumption the **primary key** fields will be used in predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses).

**Foreign Keys**:

Similar to **primary keys** these also have no measurable negative performance impact, and can also potentially help performance by guiding the database system to generate a more efficient **execution plan** in specific cases. (I find this to be a rare occurrence though and most times there's no performance difference one way or the other.)

**Clustered Indexes**:

The **clustered index** on a table can definitely **improve** performance when the fields of that index are commonly queried on in a predicate, and in most cases it's recommended to have one on a table. The **clustered index** is the logical ordering of the data in the table itself and therefore doesn't take up any additional space. Without a **clustered index** the table is logically stored in a **heap** (or similar data structure, depending on database system) which *can* be inefficient to read data from. A **clustered index** on a table *can* result in `INSERT` operations taking slightly longer, but the difference of generally milliseconds for `INSERT` operations is usually worth the tradeoff for the major performance improvements of `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries.

The edge cases where there might be a net loss in performance from using a **clustered index** is when you use a **staging table** to temporarily store the data before it's moved elsewhere, and you don't plan to do any querying against that table other than `INSERT` operations or selecting the entire table.